# recursion process in a void function

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, void, backtracking

I just found a [subset sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum) code snippet(python) in stackoverflow. Due to fascination, I translated the code snippet to C language(a mistake of course).

**My code snippet**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int top = 0;

void print(int *partial)
{
        int j =0;
        while(partial[j] != 0)
        {
                printf("%d ",partial[j]);
                j++;
        }
}
void subset(int *nos,int *partial,int reqvalue,int maxvalue) {
        int par_sum = 0,i = 0,count=0;
        while(partial[i] != 0)
        {
                par_sum += partial[i];
                i++;
        }

        if(par_sum == reqvalue)
        {
                print(partial);

        }
        if(par_sum > reqvalue)
        {
                 return ;
        }
        while(nos[count]!= 0)
        {
                count++;
        }
        for(int j =0; j < count; j++)
        {
                  int n;
                  int remaining[count+1];
                  n = nos[j];
                  for(int k = j+1; k < count+1; k++) {
                        remaining[k-(j+1)] = nos[k];
                  }
                  partial[top] = n;
                  top++;
                  subset(remaining,partial,reqvalue,maxvalue);
                  top--;
        }

}
int main()
{
        int reqvalue,no_count,sum = 0;
        int *nos;
        int *partial;
        scanf("%d %d",&reqvalue,&no_count);
        nos = calloc(( no_count+1),sizeof(int));
        partial = calloc(no_count, sizeof(int));
        for(int i =no_count-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
                scanf("%d",&nos[i]);
                sum += nos[i];

        }
        subset(nos,partial,reqvalue,sum);
        return 0;
}

#Input
#100 10
#4 14 15 18 29 32 36 82 95 95

#Output
#82 18 82 14 4 82 14 4 36 32 18 14
```

I'm just wondering, how can I print only the first subset instead of printing all subsets?
How can I break immediately from the recursion mechanism after printing the first subset ?
**Expected Output**

```
82 18
```

**Original python snippet**

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    s = sum(partial)

    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s == target: 
        print "sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target)
    if s >= target:
        return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n]) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    subset_sum([3,9,8,4,5,7,10],15)

    #Outputs:
    #sum([3, 8, 4])=15
    #sum([3, 5, 7])=15
    #sum([8, 7])=15
    #sum([5, 10])=15
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the translation to c is correct, you only output the subset in the clause

```c
if(par_sum == reqvalue)
    print(partial);
```

Hence to print only the first one you can return at the end of this clause, and make sure that the `for` loop breaks as well, e.g. by using `subset`'s return code (changing it to `int`, for example), like so:

```c
#define BREAK_LOOP 1    // before subset 

int subset(int *nos,int *partial,int reqvalue,int maxvalue) 
{
...
```

Modify the output clause to return `BREAK_LOOP` and return 0 in the other case:

```c
if(par_sum == reqvalue)
{
    print(partial);
    return BREAK_LOOP; 
}        

if(par_sum > reqvalue)
    return 0;
```

Modify the for loop to check `subset` return value, and return 0 otherwise.

```c
int subset_ret_val = 0; 
for(int j =0; j < count; j++)
{
   ...
   subset_ret_val = subset(remaining,partial,reqvalue,maxvalue);
   if (subset_ret_val)
       return subset_ret_val; 
   top--;
}
return 0;
```

If you can/would not change the function's return type to `int`, you can equivalently pass another pointer argument. If you cannot modify the function signature at all, you can still probably do some hack abusing existing arguments, but you did not seem to request a solution for that.